# TFS extension - Restrict access to a hub group

Tags: tfs

I am developing an extension for TFS (Team Foundation Server), specifically version 2017, using JavaScript.

In this extension, I am adding a Hub Group (see picture below)

[image: The Hub Group I am adding]

However, this Hub Group should only be accessible/visible to certain users.
How do I accomplish this? I have not been able to find this feature in the TFS extension tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's impossible either from extension side or permission side. Even with the build-in hub group such as Code/ Work /Build and Release. There is also not able to directly hide the hub group. Unless you change the access levels.

> Assign Stakeholder access to those users who need to **enter bugs,
>   view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards,** but who don't have a
>   TFS CAL. Stakeholders can also view releases and manage release
>   approvals. Stakeholder access is free.
>
> *Source Link: [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels)*

[image]

See [Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder) for details of features available to stakeholders.

Most extensions require that users have at least **Basic** access, not Stakeholder.

---

In your case, I will not suggest you directly change the user access level. Since he will also lose other features he had before. As a  workaround, it's able to forbid him to see or use the things under hub group/hub you have on TFS. This is another concept called **[Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level)**  in TFS.

For example, you could be able to deny the **Read** permission for branch/folder level

> ***Read***
>
> Can read the contents of a file or folder. If a user has Read
>   permissions for a folder, the user can see the contents of the folder
>   and the properties of the files in it, even if the user does not have
>   permission to open the files.